# Handle select click event datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, selection, handler

My WinForm project in c#, I have DataGridview that i want to disable cell selection with mouse clicking in editing.

To be more specific; when the user keypress"=" en event fired and disable to select cell by clicking.I want to do something different instead of cell selection. Only by keypressing"ESC" or "Enter" allow to leave cell editing.

I added picture for understanding.Please help.
[image]

Comment: Without seeing what you have attempted, I suggest you start by looking at the grids `EditingControlShowing` event. This event will fire when a cell goes into “edit” mode. In the event, the code can cast the cell as a text box, then wire up the text boxes `KeyPressed` or other events to capture the keys pressed while the cell is in “edit” mode.

Comment: Thanx for your attention. I want to give an example from excell application. In worksheet when u keypress "="on cell it is not leaving cell and while editing if you clicked different cell it is catching them.   Example " =A5+A6 ".

Comment: What you are describing is creating an Excel type application that uses a `DataGridView.` This is certainly doable; however, it will not be trivial. You would need a global variable to know when/what cell is in “edit” mode to allow the clicking of the other cells to add to the formula… then you will need additional code to translate and perform the “=” function for each cell. As I said this is doable, but reinventing the Excel wheel will not be trivial by a long shot.

Comment: I do not want to dissuade you from doing this, but I do want to point out that even your simple example is not going to be easy. This will involve quite a bit of code, work and testing. I commend your effort, but I question if you are aware of what is involved. It is unclear what the goal is, but I would think it would be easier to allow the user to do this in Excel, then after the user is done, read the Excel file from your code. Is there some reason you do not want to do this in Excel?

Comment: @JohnG. Yea. u are right.i could not find any info about this solution.But i will wait another answers:-). If not i will think another solutions. Thanx giving time.

Comment: You may be able find a third-party library that has an Excel like grid. However, I doubt it will be a free library. Again, I am not trying to dissuade you from doing this, but it seems to me that reinventing Excel will be a HUGE effort that is not necessary. Lastly, can you answer my simple question… “why” do you want to do this instead of using Excel?

Comment: @JohnG . i am a civil engineer and i am working costruction company. I have made a small program with excel but it includes material price that should be secret. Also it has huges formulas. When user work with excel file, sometimes user can damages formulas unconsciously so results will be wrong. So i decided to make desktop application with using datagridview. I have finished it actually. But the users want more flexible So i want to improve.it.

Comment: Is VBA an option? I could be mistaken and I am just saying VBA is directly plugged into the workbook itself. VBA allows you wire up events, forms, menus etc.… “directly” into the workbook. I am confident Excel using VBA can do what you describe with the cells like “=A5+B6” without you having to write a whole Excel app. In addition, I will assume the users would be more familiar with Excels interface. Just a thought.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228558/discussion-between-gokhan-and-johng).

Comment: @JohnG.  Actually i started programming with  Excel VBA,but my bosses asked me if it is possible to transition to desktop apllication. They want to take licence and make it company application. Then i started to learn C# about one year. I created thirty forms. I added datagridview many functionality. For example when the user keypress in cell "=(5+3)*3-2" it gives directly result "24". After getting this point I can not turn back now. I am at the end of this.