# Detect when the key pressed is the first char

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, keypress

I've added a KeyPress event handler to my DataGridView. If user presses "=" in a Cell, this event fires. But the `=` key must be first char.
How can I detect whether the pressed key is the first char?

I used the code shown here for this. I've made a string variable, named `meter`. It keeps the last pressed key, so I can understand from the length of `meter` if it's the first char or not.
It is worked actually, but when user deletes the key then it gives the wrong result.
Is there anyone give me some advice? Maybe different solution?

```
// this keeps pressed key and makes string. 
string meter = string.Empty; 

void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   // if the first pressed "=" key. Then meter="=". So meter length=1
   meter = meter +e.KeyChar.ToString();

   if (meter.Length == 1)
   {
      //if user keypress "="
      if (e.KeyChar == '=')
      {
          //do things
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: To what Control is the `Control_KeyPress` attached to? -- Note that you can use the `KeyDown` event, check whether a `=` char is already there: if there's one, the suppress the key, otherwise, add it yourself in first position. I assume a User cannot add more than one `=` to these Cells. You can also use a custom TextBox or RichTextBox Control in a custom `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and add all the logic in the Custom Control.

Comment: @Jimi your idea about custom comtrol inspire me to think text value changed option. Datagridview control has not text changed event but I added from "EditingControlShowing" event to cell "textChange" event. so it allow me to detect text is empty or not. Finally it is fixed without adding any custom. Thanx again.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution. I explain how to solve for other users If they face the similar problem.

First of all thanx to @Jimi. He gave me the idea.

I added "cellTb" object that represents the cell textbox using "EditingControlShowing" event.So it allows me to detect text is "=" or not. Here is the codes.

```
DataGridViewCell currentCell;
TextBox cellTb; // this represents cell textbox
private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
  {     
  e.Control.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyUp);
   currentCell = this.dgv.CurrentCell;
   cellTb = (TextBox)e.Control;
  }
    
                    
void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) //  
{
  if (cellTb.Text == "=") // this is my check operations.
     {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D0)  //if user keyup "=" 
             {
               //do things
              }
 
      }

}
```

Edit: Explanation

@Harald Coppoolse.Actually it is my fault not telling exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to try something similar excel aplication. If the user press “=”, then he/she can selects columns then when press Enter the result will shown. But the problem is after the user pressed “=” then selecting another cell make cursor leaves the main cell. I asked question about that before. There is a link below. But what i asked is some diffucult to make possible. @JohnG.( commenter)  advice me to use textbox control.

[Handle select click event datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141874/handle-select-click-event-datagridview)

Its seems sense. So i decided to used textbox. I added picture for easy understanding how i perform it.

[image]

For now it seems succeeded but i do not know which problems will be occur in the future.

I want to touch on the points you draw attention.

> “What would happen if the operator keeps the equal sign down for a
> while,”

I tried now it returns string like that“=====”. This is user problem.

> “what if the operator selects several rows and presses the equal sign?
> And what about copy-paste to paste the equal sign, or drag and drop?”

Actually i never think about this situations. But i ll try if conditions.

In a conclusion i ll change my codes according to your directions.

Thank you very much and your time.

Comment: Playing the devil’s advocate. I am confident you need to test this solution closer. Since I do not see anywhere in the code where the cell’s `KeyPress` event handler is “turned off,” I will assume it is being turned off in some other event like the grids, `CellEndEdit` event. If the code does not turn the handler off “for each cell” after editing is done, then the code will be wiring up the same event to different cells. Therefore… as the user “edits” more and more different cells, the event will fire once for each previously edited cell.

Comment: Also, have you tested the logic on the line… `cellTb.Text == ""` … this will return `false` if there IS text in the cell, however, if the text is selected and the user “replaces” the selected text with a single “=” character, this logic breaks. This logic just looks for the text without regard to what is possibly selected. Have you tested this when there is text already in the cell and you “replace” the text with a single “=” character?

Comment: Lastly, if you want to “validate” the text the user types into a cell, it may be easier to check this when the user tries to “leave” the cell as opposed to checking each key pressed. Checking the key presses will involve backspaces, selections, insertions and pasting text among other possible ways to “edit” the text in a cell. IMHO, let the user do what they want and just check the result when they try to leave the cell.

Comment: @JohnG thanx for your notification. I edited the codes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is wise to react on KeyPress. What would happen if the operator keeps the equal sign down for a while, so that a KeyPress appears rapidly after each other, or what if the operator selects several rows and presses the equal sign?

And what about copy-paste to paste the equal sign, or drag and drop?

I think what you want is this:

> Whenever the operator is editing DataGridViewTextBoxCell X of the DataGridView, and during editing the contents of the EditingControl of the cell X contains only the equal sign, I want to call procedure MyProcedure(DataGridViewCell cell)

(TODO: invent proper name for MyProcedure)

So you don't want this when the operator has finished editing the cell, you want this **during cell editing.**

For this you need access to the [DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxeditingcontrol?view=net-5.0)
This object is only available while the DataGridViewTextBoxCell class is in edit mode. You get access to the object just before the operator starts editing via event [DataGridView.EditingControlShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing?view=net-5.0)

Using visual studio designer:

```
this.dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += this.OnEditingControlShowing);
```

In the event handler you subscribe to the [TextChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netframework-4.6.1&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.TextChanged);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) of the editing control that is about to be shown

```
private void OnEditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.TextChanged += ShownEditingControl_TextChanged;
}
```

Now whenever the operator types something in the Cell's editing control, you get notified:

```
private void ShownEditingControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl shownEditingControl =
        (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)sender;

    // Do what you want to do:
    Debug.WriteLine(shownEditingControl.Text);
}
```

You can do what you want to do if the text contains only the equal sign, or if the text has several characters with the equal sign as first character.

```
if (shownEditingControl.Text == "="
{
    // do what you want to do if the operator edited only the equal sign
    // for example:
    DataGridView dgv = shownEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView;
    DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.CurrentCell;
    MyProcedure(cell);
}
```